# how to create tf.feature_columns with data have no header(csv file)?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, sklearn-pandas

I am dealing with multi-class_classification_of_handwritten_digits in the following link [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/multi-class_classification_of_handwritten_digits.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=multiclass-colab&hl=en#scrollTo=6sfw3LH0Oycm)

Then I tried to put the code in my way to re write, feed and train the DNN.
Due to the csv file has no header I am not able to create my feature columns, so I cannot train my model.

Can you please help me to figure out how it has been done in the link or how it need to be for my code? Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf

mnist_df = pd.read_csv("https://download.mlcc.google.com/mledu-datasets/mnist_train_small.csv",header=None)

mnist_df.columns

hand_df = mnist_df[0]
hand_df.head()

matrix_df = mnist_df.drop([0],axis=1)
matrix_df.head()

mnist_df = mnist_df.head(10000)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(matrix_df, hand_df, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(data=scaler.fit_transform(matrix_df),
                         columns=matrix_df.columns,
                         index=matrix_df.index)

input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train,
                                                 batch_size=10,
                                                 num_epochs=1000,
                                                 shuffle=True)

my_optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.03)

my_optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer, 5.0)

model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feat_cols,
                                      n_classes=10,
                                      optimizer=my_optimizer,
                      config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(keep_checkpoint_max=1))

model.train(input_fn=input_func,steps=1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to find a way to use data without any column names, I have had an idea that :) I have named all my columns and append them into `cols=[]` then it was easy to assign and use by `feature_columns = cols`.

Here is my full working code for my own question.

Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf 

from sklearn import metrics
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset

mnist_df = pd.read_csv("https://download.mlcc.google.com/mledu-datasets/mnist_train_small.csv",header=None)

mnist_df.describe()

mnist_df.columns

hand_df = mnist_df[0]

matrix_df = mnist_df.drop([0],axis=1)

matrix_df.head()

hand_df.head()

#creating cols array and append a1 to a784 in order to name columns
cols=[]
for i in range(785):
    if i!=0:
        a = '{}{}'.format('a',i)
        cols.append(a)

matrix_df.columns = cols

mnist_df = mnist_df.head(10000)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(matrix_df, hand_df, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(data=scaler.fit_transform(matrix_df),
                         columns=matrix_df.columns,
                         index=matrix_df.index)

#naming columns so I will not get error while assigning feature_columns
for i in range(len(cols)):
    a=i+1
    b='{}{}'.format('a',a)
    cols[i] = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(str(b))

matrix_df.head()

input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train,
                                                 batch_size=10,num_epochs=1000,
                                                 shuffle=True)

my_optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.03)

my_optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer, 5.0)

model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=cols,
                                   hidden_units=[32,64],
                                      n_classes=10,
                                      optimizer=my_optimizer,
                                      config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(keep_checkpoint_max=1))

model.train(input_fn=input_func,steps=1000)

predict_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_test,
                                                         batch_size=50,
                                                         num_epochs=1,
                                                         shuffle=False)

pred_gen = model.predict(predict_input_func)

predictions = list(pred_gen)

predictions[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The example code is already splitting the dataset into training and validation sets.

And I don't think this has anything to do with the header in the CSV.

```
training_targets, training_examples = parse_labels_and_features(mnist_dataframe[:7500])

validation_targets, validation_examples = parse_labels_and_features(mnist_dataframe[7500:10000])
```

So the training code is here separately.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset
import numpy as np


mnist_df = pd.read_csv("https://download.mlcc.google.com/mledu-datasets/mnist_train_small.csv",sep=",",header=None)

mnist_df = mnist_df.head(10000)


dataset = mnist_df[:7500]
labels = dataset[0]
print ( labels.shape )

# DataFrame.loc index ranges are inclusive at both ends.
features = dataset.loc[:, 1:784]
print ( features.shape )
# Scale the data to [0, 1] by dividing out the max value, 255.
features = features / 255


def create_training_input_fn(feature, label, batch_size, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
    """A custom input_fn for sending MNIST data to the estimator for training.

    Args:
      features: The training features.
      labels: The training labels.
      batch_size: Batch size to use during training.

    Returns:
      A function that returns batches of training features and labels during
      training.
    """

    def _input_fn(num_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
        # Input pipelines are reset with each call to .train(). To ensure model
        # gets a good sampling of data, even when number of steps is small, we
        # shuffle all the data before creating the Dataset object
        idx = np.random.permutation(feature.index)
        raw_features = {"pixels": feature.reindex(idx)}
        raw_targets = np.array(label[idx])

        ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((raw_features, raw_targets))  # warning: 2GB limit
        ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

        if shuffle:
            ds = ds.shuffle(10000)

        # Return the next batch of data.
        feature_batch, label_batch = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        return feature_batch, label_batch

    return _input_fn



my_optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.03)

my_optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer, 5.0)

model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=set([tf.feature_column.numeric_column('pixels', shape=784)]),
                                      n_classes=10,
                                      optimizer=my_optimizer,
                                      config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(keep_checkpoint_max=1))

model.train(input_fn=create_training_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size=10),steps=1000)
```

Similarly you have a function for preparing the validation set for prediction. You could use this pattern as it is.

But if you are splitting the dataframe using `train_test_split` you can try this.

```
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(mnist_df, test_size=0.2)
```

You have to repeat the following procedure for `X_test` as well to get the validation features and labels.

```
X_train_labels = X_train[0]
print ( X_train_labels.shape )

# DataFrame.loc index ranges are inclusive at both ends.
X_train_features = X_train.loc[:, 1:784]
print ( X_train_features.shape )
# Scale the data to [0, 1] by dividing out the max value, 255.
X_train_features = X_train_features / 255
```